# Correct way to inherit from std::exception

Tags: c++, exception

I've just created exception hierarchy and wanted to pass `char*` to constructor of one of my derived classes with a message telling what's wrong, but apparently `std::exception` doesn't have constructor which would allow me to do so. Yet there is a class member called `what()` which would suggest that some information can be passed.
How can I (can I?) pass text to derived class of a `std::exception` in order to pass info with my exception class, so I can say somewhere in the code:

```
throw My_Exception("Something bad happened.");
```

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but you might wanna read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/cppexceptionsproetcontra.aspx) before you start using exceptions. There are also many questions here on stack overflow about exceptions being good or bad (the answer mostly being bad).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1669514/52074 is extremely similar (almost seems like duplicate) and has more upvotes. FYI both this question and the link have the same solutions.

Comment: This one has a the better answers IMO.  Both obmarg's at the top as well as Johannes's alllll the way at the bottom.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

If you want to make use of the string constructor, you should inherit from [std::runtime_error](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error) or [std::logic_error](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/logic_error) which implements a string constructor and implements the std::exception::what method.

Then it's just a case of calling the runtime_error/logic_error constructor from your new inherited class, or if you're using c++11 you can use constructor inheritance.

Answer (score 76):

I use the following class for my exceptions and it works fine:

```
class Exception: public std::exception
{
public:
    /** Constructor (C strings).
     *  @param message C-style string error message.
     *                 The string contents are copied upon construction.
     *                 Hence, responsibility for deleting the char* lies
     *                 with the caller. 
     */
    explicit Exception(const char* message)
        : msg_(message) {}

    /** Constructor (C++ STL strings).
     *  @param message The error message.
     */
    explicit Exception(const std::string& message)
        : msg_(message) {}

    /** Destructor.
     * Virtual to allow for subclassing.
     */
    virtual ~Exception() noexcept {}

    /** Returns a pointer to the (constant) error description.
     *  @return A pointer to a const char*. The underlying memory
     *          is in posession of the Exception object. Callers must
     *          not attempt to free the memory.
     */
    virtual const char* what() const noexcept {
       return msg_.c_str();
    }

protected:
    /** Error message.
     */
    std::string msg_;
};
```

Comment: where did the "msg_" keyword came from? I did not know you can call statement after the ":" of a method declaration. I think this was only for base class.

Comment: msg_ is a **protected** member of Exception; it's an instance of std::string, so it has access to it's .c_str member function (converts to c string).

Comment: what about copy constructor?

Comment: @DDrmmr You should explain why.

Comment: @Water This code does the same as `std::runtime_error`. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. Constructing an std::string can throw an exception, which will cause terminate to be called.

Comment: i agree with @DDrmmr's statement that you are reinventing the wheel (i.e. you are re-implementing `std::runtime_error` or `std::logic_error`).

Comment: Your exception does not satisfy requirement of exception design. During construction std::string constructor is called, which may throw an exception. I would say, it's a very unlikely situation, but this code is not well-formed and would not have passed my review. It could be designed in a proper way with a sophisticated class member std::unique_ptr<std::string>. In this case exception may not thrown from your exception c-tor

Answer (score 15):

How about this:

```
class My_Exception : public std::exception
{
public:
virtual char const * what() const { return "Something bad happend."; }
};
```

Or, create a constructor accepting the description if you like...

Comment: @user472155 +1 for the good answer. By the way though, I think it worth to mention here, that the signature you provided in your example for the what function, implies only to code prior to C++11.

Comment: @Guy Avraham: do you mean that post C++11 the virtual keyword should become override, or something else?

Comment: @gg99 - Good point. I meant that since C++11, the signature of the `what` function turned into the following: `virtual const char* what() const noexcept` (note the addition of the `noexcept` keyword at the end). See also here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/what

Answer (score 15):

If your goal is to create an exception so that you do not throw a generic exception ([cpp:S112](https://rules.sonarsource.com/cpp/RSPEC-112)) you may just want to expose the exception you inherit from ([C++11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration)) with a using declaration.

Here is a minimal example for that:

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

struct myException : std::exception
{
    using std::exception::exception;
};

int main(int, char*[])
{
    try
    {
        throw myException{ "Something Happened" };
    }
    catch (myException &e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return{ 0 };
}
```

As Kilian points out in the comment section the example depends on a specific implementation of std::exception that offers more constructors than are mentioned [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/exception).

In order to avoid that you can use any of the convenience classes predefined in the header `<stdexcept>`. See these "[Exception categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error)" for inspiration.

Comment: Having a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/exception std::exception does not have a constructor taking a string as argument. So your code is ill-formed.

Comment: @Kilian I am using implementation specific behavior which should be common and practical. Thanks for the hint I will include that in the answer.

Answer (score 7):

The `what` method is virtual, and the meaning is that you should override it to return whatever message you want to return.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example

```
 class CommunicationError: public std::exception {
  public:
   explicit CommunicationError(const char* message) : msg(message) {}
   CommunicationError(CommunicationError const&) noexcept = default;

   CommunicationError& operator=(CommunicationError const&) noexcept = default;
  ~CommunicationError() override = default;

  const char* what() const noexcept override { return msg; }
 private:
  const char* msg;
};
```

[1] https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/adaptive/17-03/AUTOSAR_RS_CPP14Guidelines.pdf