# Is there any way to print its information when met an uncaught exception that is not from STL?

Tags: c++, c++11

When compiler meets an exception that is from STL like `std::out_of_range` :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    throw std::out_of_range("There is an exception!");
}
```

the console will show the message :

`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: There is an exception!`

So I wrote an exception class :

```
class Exception {
    protected:
        const char *msg;
    public:
        Exception(const char *msg) noexcept : msg(msg) {}
        Exception(const string &msg) noexcept : msg(msg.c_str()) {}
        const char *what() const noexcept {
            return this->msg;
        }
};
```

However, throwing `Exception` will not get any information :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    throw Exception("There is an exception!");
}
```

Console message :

`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type Exception`

Is there any way making console show :

`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type Exception: There is an exception!`

Compiler : `Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)`

Comment: What happens if you inherit from `std::exception`?

Comment: What is the reason to reimplement your own exception hierarchy? What's wrong with the standard C++ exceptions? Why can't you inherit from them? What is the *real* problem you want to solve using non-standard exceptions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating custom exceptions in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41753358/creating-custom-exceptions-in-c)

Comment: Your `Exception(const string &)` constructor is very likely to store a pointer which becomes invalid when stack unwinding destroys the original `std::string` object.

Comment: If you want to control what happens when an exception is thrown, **catch it**. The language definition doesn't require any sort of display for an uncaught exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you derive your exception class publicly from `std::exception` then the compiler provided exception handler will be able to print more information for your exception.