# Why to use throw in the definition of a method?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, throw

I am trying to implement a new exception for our code base and I came across this post in SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8152888/654019

but I am not sure why the what method is defined as follow:

```
virtual const char* what() const throw (){
    return msg_.c_str();
}
```

What is the meaning of throw in this context?

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1055387/335858).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight ok, so it says that the code doesn't generate any exception.

Comment: In new code you probably want to use `noexcept` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is [dynamic exception specification](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec), which is deprecated since C++11, and removed from C++17.

`throw()` is used to specify that the function won't throw any exceptions (directly or indirectly), from C++11 we should use `noexcept` or `noexcept(true)` instead.

Comment: `noexcept` was added in C++11. So while it's correct to say that you shouldn't use it in C++17, you shouldn't use dynamic exception specifications with C++11 either.

Comment: @NicolBolas You meant `throw()` shouldn't be used since C++11, all dynamic exception specifications shouldn't be used since C++17. Is the understanding correct?

Comment: Well, you shouldn't be using any dynamic exception specifications in C++11, since they were deprecated. It's just that C++17 finally removed all of the non-empty ones.

Comment: I believe VS 2013 doesn't implement them yet, so I stuck to this for aa while I think.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes I see.