# Getting Error expected initializer before 'throw' in C++ Exception Handling Problem

Tags: c++, function, exception, error-handling, try-catch

I am trying to solve the Hacker rank Inherited Code problem and getting the error I cannot solve myself.
I have taken reference from GFG to learn about Exception handling and
bad_exception:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exception-handling-c/
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exceptionbad_exception-in-c-with-examples/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;
void BadLengthException(int n) throw(int) throw(bad_exception)
{
    if(n){
        throw n;
    }
}
bool checkUsername(string username) {
    bool isValid = true;
    int n = username.length();
    if(n < 5) {
        throw BadLengthException(n);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
        if(username[i] == 'w' && username[i+1] == 'w') {
            isValid = false;
        }
    }
    return isValid;
}

int main() {
    int T; cin >> T;
    while(T--) {
        string username;
        cin >> username;
        try {
            bool isValid = checkUsername(username);
            if(isValid) {
                cout << "Valid" << '\n';
            } else {
                cout << "Invalid" << '\n';
            }
        } catch (BadLengthException e) {
            cout << "Too short: " << e.what() << '\n';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *I have taken reference from GFG* -- That site is notorious for bad C++ advice, coding examples, and whatever else. -- *I am trying to solve the Hacker rank Inherited Code* -- It seems you are trying to learn C++ by going to competition websites and geeksforgeeks.  Sorry, but to learn one of the most difficult computer languages out there, it requires investing in peer-reviewed books and materials.

Comment: [Your code is not legal C++17](https://godbolt.org/z/6xG576rdz).  This is the stuff you get when you use bad websites to learn C++ programming.

Comment: The dynamic exception specification syntax `throw(/*some type*/)` has been removed from C++ since C++17 and had been deprecated since C++11. It isn't valid anymore. The code is severely out-dated and won't compile on most modern compilers with default settings. The linked site is known to be full of errors and bad advice and a horrible source to learn C++.

Comment: [Correct way to inherit from std::exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152720/correct-way-to-inherit-from-stdexception).

Comment: What changes can be made in the code to remove the error?

Comment: @Chelseajain Did you see the link I posted?  What is different in the code at the link than what you are trying to do?  The main difference is that an exception class is created, not a standalone `BadLengthException` function.  Honestly, even mediocre, bordering on bad websites would show how to create and throw C++ exceptions, which shows you how horrible GFG is.