# Is there any advantages to throw other thing that a std::exception( or derivatives types)

Tags: c++, exception

Is there any advantages or uses cases to throw other thing that a std::exception( or a derivatives types).

For example `throw 1;` or `throw "error";`

In other terms why the c++ standard allow it.

Comment: Why should it be disallowed?

Comment: See also "Should I inherit from std::exception?" http://stackoverflow.com/q/1669514/96780

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per §15.1 [except]:

> Exception handling provides a way of transferring control and
>   **information** from a point in the execution of a thread to an exception
>   handler associated with a point previously passed by the execution.

The word *information* illustrates everything, it can be everything such as objects, numbers, ... .

There is nothing in standard that says you must just throw `std::exception`. In the other words, maybe someone wants to throw his own exception objects.

Maybe someone wants to use exception-handling to handle something far from normal exceptions.

Answer (score 4):

I can't think of any obvious reasons why a class derived from `std::exception` wouldn't typically be better.

But the `throw 1` or `throw "Error"` are valid expressions, and they probably take a bit less "effort" creating, and there may be situations where this is a benefit. Throwing an `exception` type exception from the constructor of `exception` would probably not work very well, so there's one place.

However, it's probably more of a philosophical decision: Since `throw` can be made to throw a any type of object, it's not a bad idea to allow it. The more restrictions you put on things in a language, the more you restrict the possible uses of a language.

Comment: Actually, I wrote that wrong, and have now edited. But yes, there's arguments for all manner of different options here.

Answer (score 3):

From reference material about std::exception:

> **std::exception**
>
> All objects thrown by components of the standard library are derived
>   from this class. Therefore, all standard exceptions can be caught by
>   catching this type by reference.

By throwing anything else, for example `NuclearPlantException`, you could handle your exceptions and the ones from the standard library separately. The standard library could throw `std::invalid_argument` or `std::bad_alloc` (subtypes of `std::exception`) and you could throw `LossOfCoolant` (a subtype of `NuclearPlantException`).

So there is at least one advantage: **separating standard library exceptions from your exceptions**. Because you don't throw `std::bad_alloc` if there's enough available space for your uranium, then any exception has a clear origin, potentially making testing and debugging easier.

---

**Note:** For more in-depth discussion see the question [Should I inherit from std::exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1669514/96780).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there can be advantages.

The most obvious is that the `what` for existing derivatives of `std::exception` (e.g., `std::logic_error`, `std::invalid_argument`) only deal with `std::string`s or `char *`s to specify the reason for the exception. That's probably fine if you only deal with an English speaking audience, but if you want to use the `what` to display an error message to somebody who doesn't use English, it can get clumsy in a hurry.

If you're using (for example) 32-bit Unicode strings throughout your program, you'd typically prefer do the same in your exception handling. In such a case, a hierarchy similar to those in the standard, but using 32-bit Unicode strings for the `what` argument probably makes a *lot* of sense. I suppose you *could* still use `std::exception` for the base of that hierarchy, but it's open to question how much (if anything) you'd gain from doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Throwing things was in C++ a decade before std::exception or even std:: became an idea. This was not removed for backward compatibility reasons.

Those who chose not use std:: certainly like it that way, and throw other exceptions, likely derived from some base class supplied by a library. It's fine until you get several exception hierarchies to deal with in client code.  So new code that does not fight against using std:: entirely (setting new_handler to avoid std::bad_alloc) is likely to re-fit its exception root classes to use std::exception as base.

Throwing non-class things like ints or pointers is often advised agaist, but in a light environment can make perfect sense -- in an small embedded project leaving the exceptions enabled but throwing only an enum sounds sensible.

In general, if the language allows to throw any copyable object why restrict it? While forcing to use a special library class would be not in spirit of C++ even if we had time travel.